# Vite images in react app which is rendered in an C# MVC view

Tags: reactjs, image, vite

I'm new to Vite and I have a react app loading into an ASP MVC view but I'm having trouble with images.
I think theres an issue with my config.

```
export default defineConfig({
resolve: {
    alias: {
        "Pages": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/Pages"),
        "Components": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/Components"),
        "Hooks": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/Hooks"),
        "Context": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/Context"),
        "Assets": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/Assets"),
        "Api": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/Api"),
        "Utils": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/Utils"),
    }
},
build: {
    outDir: './dist',
    rollupOptions: {
        input: {
            main: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.tsx'),
        }
    }
},
plugins: [
    react({
        include: "**/*.tsx",
        fastRefresh: false
    }),
],
});
```

Everything I try, I just keep getting a 404, but the image is trying to render from the MVC route, not the react app route.

EG MVC is localhost:3333, react is localhost:3000

Importing the image:
`import NoDataIcon from "/icon.png";`

Rendering the image:
`<img className="m-auto" src={NoDataIcon} alt="no data" />`

And the image exists in the public folder outside of src, in the root directory.

Thanks for your help.